# jQuery Datepicker - add class to the first and the last date of a selected range

Tags: jquery, datepicker, date-range

I'm using jQuery Date picker http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html

Here is html input for datepicker call:

```
<input type="text" class="date-picker-input" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy - dd/mm/yyyy ">
```

This is my jquery code for datepicker initialization:

```
 $('.date-picker-input').datepick({ 
        rangeSelect: true, 
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
        changeMonth: false,
        prevText: '<',
        nextText: '>',
        showOtherMonths: true,
        dayNamesShort: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
        showTrigger: '#calImg',
     });
  });
```

I'm using range option, and **i want to add class to the first and last date of selected range** in order to stylize them. The dates inside a range have already had *.datepick-selected* class, but they are inside < td > elements so i must point them via jquery. This is what i tried in order to generate class:

```
$('.datepick-month .datepick-selected:first, .datepick-month .datepick-selected:last').addClass('selected');
```

But nothing happened.

How it currently looks
[image: Current datapicker code]

How I want it to look
[image: Datapicker code I want to achieve]

Comment: could you show more html code, because there are lot options with datepicker

Comment: .datepick-selected  exists only when datepicker is shown, when the plugin is closed, you dont see it in the DOM, only when the plugin is opened

Comment: if you just want to keep the daye selected, you could play with onClose

Comment: I have updated my question with a screenshots. As you can see, selected "from to" dates have additional class "datepick-selected" (see my first screenshot). I want to add additional class called "selected" to the first and the last element only, which contain class "datepick-selected" (2nd screenshot).

Comment: when you do the command to add class? and i repeat could you show your html code to see how you implement the datepicker? and how you close the datepicker?  when you select the second date, its automatically close?

Comment: Yes, the datepicker html is generated in the DOM only when it is activated on input click. When i either click out of input or select the second date its automatically close and disappears from DOM . I have updated my initial post with html of the input field you asked for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED**

the only way to do that (for me) is to add a spy which checks if some class (`datepick-popup`) is present in DOM (simulate the open event which doesnt exist in the plugin):

```
    var lapse = setInterval( checkIfpickerIsOpened, 300); //you could adjust the time
    
    function checkIfpickerIsOpened(){
       if($(".datepick-popup").length > 0){
         $(".datepick-popup .datepick-selected:first, .datepick-popup .datepick-selected:last").addClass("selected");
         clearInterval(lapse);
       }
    }
   
   $('.date-picker-input').datepick({ 
        rangeSelect: true, 
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
        changeMonth: false,
        prevText: '<',
        nextText: '>',
        showOtherMonths: true,
        dayNamesShort: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
        onClose: Close,
        showTrigger: '#calImg'
  });

   function Close(){
     lapse = setInterval( checkIfpickerIsOpened, 100);      
  }
```

to see the result, you could add a css:

```
.selected {
  background-color:red !important;// *important* is needed to override default color
}
```

[image: Result]

i have found an hidden even `onShow` so its functional when we had some timeout to wait the different items of datepicker appear.

```
   $('.date-picker-input').datepick({ 
        rangeSelect: true, 
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
        changeMonth: false,
        prevText: '<',
        nextText: '>',
        showOtherMonths: true,
        dayNamesShort: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
        onShow: function(){setTimeout(Open, 200);},
        showTrigger: '#calImg'
  });

 function Open(){
  if($(".datepick-popup").length > 0){
     $(".datepick-popup .datepick-selected:first, .datepick-popup .datepick-selected:last").addClass("selected");
  }    
}
```

so you have 2 solutions!!

Comment: Thank you sir for your help. Unfortunately, it works only if start and end dates are under the same month. There is an issue with both of your codes if i need to slide to some next month in order to select end date. For example, try to select 24 April as start date and 6 May as end date, and you will see it brakes at the last day of the current month.

Comment: its another problem, we arrive at the limit of the plugin, you didnt speak about start and end date on month different (following your sample) . there is a solution but need some code..i'll suggest you to precise your question on another question to avoid to pollute this question already complex.. just fyi, when you change the month all data are updated and you dont see the precedent month in the DOM, so its thereason you need some new code

Comment: so its interesting problem..!!.

Comment: OK sir, I have opened a new ticket https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67208153/jquery-datepicker-issue-with-start-and-end-dates-classes

Comment: @Majurac please dont forget to validate and upvote the answer to close the question

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use `:first` and `:last` when you should probably be using `:first-of-type` and `:last-of-type`. Try:

```js
$('.date-picker-input .datepick-selected:first-of-type, .date-picker-input .datepick-selected:last-of-type').addClass('selected');
```

Comment: Tried that as well but it is still not generating additional class to the first and the last element,

Comment: I haven't tested your jQuery UI code - but its worth noting sibling CSS selectors like :first-of-type are intended for situations where you have siblings of the same type. Are the `.datepick-selected` elements all siblings, or are do they have different parents etc? If they have different parents (because of different calendar rows etc) try

```const elements = $('.date-picker-input .datepick-selected');
for (let i = 0; elements.length; i++) {
   const element = elements[i];
   if (i == 0 || i == (elements.length - 1)) {
       $(element).addClass('selected');
   }
}
```

Comment: .datepick-selected elements have different parents (see the screenshot under the my initial post). Tnx, i will try your code.